# JavaScript causing "A script on this page may be busy, or it may have stopped responding." error in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox

I wrote a page by javascript that has over 1000 lines of code and so the page is so heavy.
when i run the page on the firefox, it tell me that:

```
A script on this page may be busy, or it may have stopped responding. You can stop the script now, or you can continue to see if the script will complete.

Script: http://localhost:5070/resources/ir.pnusn.branch.ui.pages.BranchMap/scripts/MapAddress.js:151
```

and I have in MyAddress.js:151:

```
function fillAddress(number)
{
150:    var filedNum=0;
151:    while(document.getElementById("choice4")!=null)
        document.getElementById("choice4").click();
    nextId=1;
    for(i=0;;i++)
    {
        var cookieChoiceName=number+"-"+filedNum+"-0";
        var cookieChoiceValue=getCookie(cookieChoiceName);
        if(cookieChoiceValue==null)
        {
            //alert(document.getElementById("choice4"));
            break;
        }
        var cookieFieldName=number+"-"+filedNum+"-1";
        var cookieFieldValue=getCookie(cookieFieldName);
        if(cookieFieldValue==null)
        {
            alert(document.getElementById("choice4"));
            break;
        }
        if(cookieChoiceValue!= "-1" && cookieChoiceValue!="-2" && document.getElementById("choice"+cookieChoiceValue)!=null)
        {
            document.getElementById("choice"+cookieChoiceValue).click();
        }
        var value=utf8_decode(unescape(cookieFieldValue));
        var finalval=replacePluse(value);
        // var Resvalue=value.substr(1,value.length-1);
        document.getElementById("txt"+(filedNum-1)).value=finalval;
        filedNum++;
    }
}
```

and when I press continue in warning window the code work correctly.
but when i increase dom.max_script_run_time in firefox configuration file it does not change
and after that when I press continue again it works.
What's the problem?If you want more information about the code tell me to put for you here.

Comment: I think it is not for infinite loop because before I add some code for disabling some textfileds to page it works without this warning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `while` probably is an infinite loop. The condition you are using will always be true as long as you have element with id `#choise4` present. Since you are not removing this element inside the loop, then it will never finish.

Comment: when i click on choice4 it removes some items and remove itself and create again to arrive to first condition wich i don't have choice4

Comment: If it recreates itself then next time `while` evaluates it's condition it will still be present and you will never leave this loop

Answer (score 2):

This line looks suspiciously like a infinite loop to me:

```
while(document.getElementById("choice4")!=null)
    document.getElementById("choice4").click();
```

Answer (score 1):

From your code it looks like the onclick function for 'choice4' is supposed to remove the element but isn't doing.

I'd check for a bug in that onclick.

Comment: I did't understand what you mean.Can you explain more.